# Floated divs acting like a clear: left applied

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having a problem with floated divs. When searching for an answer most questions were how to achieve the effect I am getting instead of how to achieve what I want. Basically I'm floating divs to create 3 columns and the desired outcome is the fourth div, which should be in column 1 directly below the first div, begins where the third floated div ends in height instead of where the one directly above it, the first div, ends. The code below in the latest chrome demonstrates what I don't want.

The effect I'm getting is like I expect clear: left; to behave if applied to the fourth floated div.

The code below works only on a resolution where 3 * 400px is less than the screen width but 4 * 400 is greater than screen width.

This image shows what's happening, I want the fourth div where I've shown with an arrow instead of where it is: http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2613/desired.png

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .div1
        {
            float: left;
            background-color: black;
            height: 100px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        .div2
        {
            background-color: red;
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            float: left;
        }
        .div3
        {
            float: left;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 500px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        .div4
        {
            background-color: green;
            float: left;
            height: 100px;
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div4"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position):

> The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the
>   source document.

You may be interested in the [jQuery masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Perfect resource for this issue!

Answer (score 0):

If your able to change the HTML slightly then you could group div1 and div4 together:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .group1 {
            float: left;
        }
        .div1
        {
            float: left;
            background-color: black;
            height: 100px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        .div2
        {
            background-color: red;
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            float: left;
        }
        .div3
        {
            float: left;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 500px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        .div4
        {
            clear: both;
            background-color: green;
            height: 100px;
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="group1">
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>


</body>
</html>​​​
```

Comment: As easy as this is in the context I've given, my problem involved a highly dynamic set of divs and heights, thanks for the help though.